# How to add Click event handler to TextBlock on Window phones

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am writing a application for c# on windows phones. 
I create a TextBlock in my page using xaml. How can I add click event handler in xaml. I tried using 'Click' as attribute, but that is not a valid attribute for TextBlock.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you retemplate a Button with a TextBlock instead?

Comment: `Tap` event should be available for `TextBlock`. IIRC I used that instead of click.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the `Tapped`event (Sopuli was almost right). Just a tip for you: on the right hand side of the window is the property explorer. If you click on the event icon on the upper right you will get a list of all events the control exposes.

Just double click inside one of the fields next to the text and the Visual Studio will create the event for you and put a handler in the code behind file.

[image: Event Handlers]

Answer (score 0):

Correct, a TextBlock does not have a Click event. However, if you go to the Object Browser and search for TextBlock, you may find an alternative event.